# Mutating error when attempting to append an array of a struct

Tags: ios, swift, struct, immutability, swiftui

I'm attempting to create an action within a SwiftUI `Form` to add an additional `Child` to my data set. When I try to append `newChild` I get an error:

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

```
struct Child : Identifiable {

   var id = UUID()
   var birthday: Date
   var name: String

}

struct ContentView: View {

    var children : [Child] = []

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
              Button(action: {
                  let newChild = Child(birthday: Date(), name: "Carl")
                  children.append(newChild)
              }) {
                  Text("Add Child")
              }
        }
    }
}
```

My array `children` is mutable from what I can tell, so why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that a `struct` cannot change its own properties without the function that is changing those properties being marked `mutating`. You can’t mark `body` as `mutating`, but you can make `children` a `@State var`. `@State` variables are mutable, but only from within your view’s `body` property.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I was declaring my array `children` within the struct where it was being mutated. Moving the declaration outside of the struct ran without error.